# Extreme rays of a polyhedral

Tags: linear-programming, polyhedra

I was reading the following https://faculty.coe.drexel.edu/jwalsh/eces811/linProg.pdf, and was confused at one of the lines.

They defined a polyhedral cone to be

$$\{y\in \mathbb{R}^N | Hy≤0\}.$$

Also, an extreme ray is a $\{\gamma y_∗|\gamma  ≥ 0\}$ in the cone such that if

$$\{\gamma y_∗|\gamma  ≥ 0\} = \mu_1\{\gamma y_1|\gamma  ≥ 0\} + \mu_2\{\gamma y_2|\gamma  ≥ 0\}$$ for some $\mu_1,\mu_2>0$, and if $\{\gamma y_1|\gamma  ≥ 0\} , \{\gamma y_2|\gamma  ≥ 0\}$ are both in the cone, then
$$ \{\gamma y_∗|\gamma  ≥ 0\} = \{\gamma y_1|\gamma  ≥ 0\} =\{\gamma y_2|\gamma  ≥ 0\}.$$

My understanding of this is an extreme ray is some direction that cannot be written as a linear combination of any other point in the cone (is that correct?).

My confusion comes in on this line

> This will happen if and only if $y_∗$ obeys exactly $N −1$ linearly
> independent rows of $Hy ≤ 0$ with equality.

How do I interpret a cone (geometrically)? and why would solving these active constraints give extreme rays?

Comment: It just occured to me a ray has one dimension, and therefore $N-1$ constraints is enough to uniquely produce such a ray.

Comment: Search images for "cone extreme ray" to get an intuition of what it looks like geometrically. Extreme rays for cones are the pendant of vertices for polytopes. For vertices, you need $N$ linearly independent rows, for rays, only $N-1$, since you have a degree of freedom.